# All links stop working after opening Editor.js Component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, editorjs

I recently started using `Editor.js` in an angular application I'm building but there's been a recurring issue of which I'm not sure what's really going on. Upon integration with my angular application, `Editor.js` seems to behave fine, but this is only on the surface. When I click on the link that directs me to the component where `Editor.js` is placed, the link opens at first then I go back using the back navigation and automatically all links on the return page stop working including the link that goes to `Editor.js`. There is no error on the console and angular isn't showing errors either. All that happens is the links stop working, when I reload the page it seems to start working and then I click the link to the Editor.js component and it returns to the original behaviour. I can't seem to figure it out. Is there any way I can determine where this error is coming from and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the code below as a quick hack. On reloading the links worked fine, however using angular router directly this lead to all the links freezing, so I used the code below to ensure when a user goes back from the **Editor.js** Component, the page is reloaded instead. importing the Location and Router modules.

```
this._location.subscribe((data) => {
    if(data.pop){
      this._router.navigateByUrl(data.url)
      .then(() => {
        window.location.reload();
      });
    }
  })
```

If there is a better way I'm open to suggestions. Thanks.